# grep won't work after swap standard input and standard error

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, file-descriptor, nohup

I run command and I want to eliminate lines containing "nohup" from standard error. In order to do so I swap standard input and standard error and I filter "nohup". Then I swap them again in order to go back to the inicial state. Like this:

```
nohup COMMAND 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | grep -v nohup 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 &
```

Then I tee to a file, and I filter out a password:

```
nohup COMMAND 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | grep -v nohup 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3  | tee FILE.log | grep -v "password" &
```

What I can't figure out is why `grep -v "password"` won't work here.

If I don't do the double file descriptor swap it does:

```
nohup COMMAND  | tee FILE.log | grep -v "password" &
```

Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Grep doesn't write anything to stderr.

Comment: what is file descriptor 3? normally 0=stdin, 1=stdout, 2=stderr

Answer (score 2):

In `nohup COMMAND 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | grep -v nohup 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3`, you swapped stdout and stderr of `nohup`, and the erstwhile stderr goes to the pipe. Where does the erstwhile stdout out go? To wherever stderr originally pointed, which is presumably the terminal. The swap for `grep` won't affect *that*.

You probably need to do something like:

```
(nohup COMMAND 2>&1 1>&3 | grep -v nohup 1>&2) 3>&1 | tee FILE.log | grep -v "password" &
```

Or using bash process substitution to send just stderr to grep:

```
nohup COMMAND 2> >(grep -v nohup >&2) | tee FILE.log | grep -v "password" &
```